# Как выполнить Node.js код на HTML странице?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Я создаю веб-приложение на electron и node.js. Мне нужно выполнить код для запуска .exe программы при нажатии на кнопку через HTML страницу. Вот мой код для запуска (renderer.js):

```js
const exec = require('child_process').execFile;

let run = function(){
   exec('C:/Test/Test.exe');  
}
run();
```

Мне нужно чтобы этот код выполнялся только после нажатия на кнопку на HTML странице.

Answer (score 0):

Поставь запуск функции у кнопки на свойство onClick.

```html
<button onClick="run()">Button</button>
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал. Не помогло, onclick запускает только js код, а не node.js. И в итоге в консоли высвечивается ошибка: "не удалось найти функцию require". Require - функция node.js